# Terminate a Thread thats running a jar

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that extends Thread and when started, it runs a jar's Main method. When I terminate the Thread it does not kill the process it started. How do I go about that? Thanks!

Below if the run() method from my custom Thread class.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        if(parent != null) {
            MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole(parent.getConsole().getTextPane());
            console.redirectOut(new Color(240, 240, 240), null);
            console.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
            console.setMessageLines(20);
        }
        if(oParent != null) {
            MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole(oParent.getConsole().getTextPane());
            console.redirectOut(new Color(240, 240, 240), null);
            console.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
            console.setMessageLines(20);
        }
        try {
            somejar.SomeJar.main(args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Engine failed to start!\nSuggestion: Restart the application, and if the issue is not fixed reinstall the application.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I terminate the Thread it does not kill the process it started. How do I go about that?

There is no reliable way to do that.

Firstly, there is no reliable way to terminate the thread.  The preferred way to **try** is to call `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread, but this may be ignored.  If you call the **deprecated** method `Thread.stop()`, you are liable to destabilize your JVM.

Second, even assuming you kill the JAR thread, you cannot reliably kill any child threads that it created.  You cannot reliably distinguish the child threads from other threads created by other parts of your application.  And if you could identify them, you cannot reliably kill them.

The best you can do is launch a new JVM as an external process to run the JAR.  Under normal circumstances a JVM can reliably kill an external process that it has created.  (There are exceptions, e.g. setuid commands, but they shouldn't be an issue here.)

Comment: @Stephen C, agree this is the best solution. If its not an option, one way you could try to identify child threads is to start the first thread in a new ThreadGroup, children will be started in the same group by default.  Its not reliable, but it may be better than nothing.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - ThreadGroups are too unreliable. For instance, if you relied on them you could end up killing threads that are not "owned" by the JAR thread.  That can be WORSE than nothing.

Comment: is there a way that I could enumerate through all the children and kill each one? Or maybe get the process id of each thread and terminate them individually?

Comment: @Stephen C, it depends on how self contained the Jar is.  This could only happen if you had callbacks which started threads you wanted to keep.

Comment: @Jacob, what you could do is Thread.getAllStackTraces() as you can search the stack traces of threads to see if they are inside the JAR.  This is also rather dangerous and unreliable.

Comment: Now when you say dangerous, what exactly do you mean? A destabilized JVM?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - it is not just callbacks.  For instance, the jar app could trigger some library classes to initialize and create worker threads ... in the jar app's ThreadGroup.  Those libraries could used by other apps in the JVM, so killing them is a bad idea.

Comment: @Stephen C, It is fairly rare for a third party library to start a thread in another third party library you happen to also need, but it could happen. If it did you could check for this.  In any case, anything other than running the library in another process is a purely pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot terminate a thread without terminating the process.

You can signal it to stop e.g. interrupt() or throw an exception, but the only way to get it to stop is for it to return or throw a Throwable from the run() method.